# JavaScript - Create an custom element and apply standard styles

Tags: javascript, css, user-agent

I'm creating a JavaScript code with custom elements, but i don't know how I must set the standard style of the element. I'm trying this:

```
switchElement.style.backgroundColor = "#555";
```

But this won't work, when I change the css stylesheet. Is there a way to set the standard style to `background-color: green`? Like:

stylesheet.css

```
background-color: blue; /*didn't make it blue*/
```

html.html

```
<switch></switch> <!--This element is custom created by JavaScript-->
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code of your webpage???

Comment: Do you want to make the CSS rules in your JS more important than the CSS  rules in CSS file?

Comment: No, they must can be changed by all stylesheets, style tags and style attributes. Like a sub-user agent.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't get you. Could you please explain it by editing your question…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your CSS rules present in JS file more important than CSS rules present in your CSS file then you should add your `<script>` tag after your `<style>` or `<link>` tag, like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Anything You Like</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "switchElement"></div>
<style>
#switchElement{
background-color : red;
}
</style>
<script>
var switchElement = document.getElementById("switch element");
switchElement.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> This will make the `switchElement` appear blue in color instead of red.

Comment: Thanks, but i already know that. But what i means is a html code like `<switch></switch>` and set the standard style, like a sub-user agent. That can be changed by all stylesheets (.css file, style tag, and style attribute).

Answer (score 0):

If your "switchElemet" variable is selecting proper element then it should work.

Check your variable whether this is an element or null . Try console.log(switchElemet).